# Can a log values combine and print final output in logstash

Tags: logstash, kibana

Hi Am working on logstash, and i have come to an scenario where i need to select final values from logs and showcase in Kibana.

For eg:

`uniq_reference 01 : Status = "Processing" uniq_reference 01 : Status = "Completed" uniq_reference 02 : Status = "Processing"`

now in Kibana if i use data filter visual am getting count as Processing - 2 and completed - 1
whereas the actual output should be Processing - 1 and completed - 1 earlier value of uniq_reference 01 should be ignored

Comment: Would it help to use a "unique count" (aka `cardinality`) metric? For example: unique count of `uniq_reference`, filtered by `Status: Processing`

Comment: Yeah if we use unique count also am getting answer as u said,but is ther any other method to , since above is just 2 example i shared the logs i have has 3 uniq reference which shares final answer as processed, but i need to ignore first 2 reference.

Comment: Check out the `top_hits` aggregation ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)) - it's available in Kibana, and can be used to the show the "latest" value of a field

Comment: Thanks a lot, was able to get the data using Top_hits, is it possible to use the same code snippet to Visualise side, Sorry am bit new to Dev tools early i have configured only visualize by adding data from logstash

Comment: You'll need to consult the kibana docs and/or click around the UI... many visualisations support `top_hits` aggregations

Comment: Sorry mate to bother..tried many ways to inject dev tools snippet to visualise, am getting as error unable to fetch aggs function, seems json input doesn't support aggs function